# Showing DialogFragment Causes IllegalStateException

Tags: android, dialog, fragment, illegalstateexception

I have a DialogFragment which I am showing when a button is clicked. I have the following code in the onClick method of the button:

```
 InfoTextDialog infoDialog = new InfoTextDialog(conditions[counter], information[counter]);
 infoDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), null);
```

However, I sometime get the following exception:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
```

This does not occur all the time, but it happens quite frequently. Can someone please explain to me what is causing this exception to be thrown, and how to solve this issue.

**EDIT 1:** Here is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1318)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1329)
at android.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:607)
at android.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:586)
at android.app.DialogFragment.show(DialogFragment.java:230)
at <...>.MyActivity$1.onClick(MyActivity.java:73)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4235)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17484)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: post the full stack trace and point to what line it is breaking on

Comment: it is breaking on this line: infoDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), null);

Answer (score 0):

hard to say without knowing more about your app - but this should help:

```
if (!getActivity().isFinishing()) {
  InfoTextDialog infoDialog = new InfoTextDialog(conditions[counter], information[counter]); 
  infoDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), null);
}
```

Comment: if getActivity().isFinishing() returns true, what the best approach to handling this situation so that the fragment still gets shown?

Comment: the dialog needs an activity to host it. you could start an activity themed as an dialog as an alternative